# How to make a replacement image when you click on Gui button&

Tags: lua, roblox

I can not understand how to change the image when you press the button

Comment: Please add examples of what you have tried, It is hard to give advise to a question that is a statement. As it stands, i can say there are a lot of roblox tutorials out there that would cover this type of topic.

Comment: What image? what button? There is no context here! Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

To change an image label's image you must first have the explorer tab open in roblox, to do this look at the top bar on your roblox game editor. Go into view and select explorer on the left of the top bar.

Now do as I do.
Add a screenGUI into the starterGUI folder
Into the screenGUI add a frame
And into the frame add the following items
a LocalScript
a TextButton
and a ImageLabel

Inside the localscript put this script

```
local label = script.Parent.ImageLabel
local frame = script.Parent

frame.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(click)
label.Image = "rbxassetid://284402785" --change this to whatever image you want but keep the quotation marks
end)
```

You can change the normal asset in the image label to whatever you want.